# Refactoring a Single Page web app in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, single-page-application

I have a small SPA web app that uses Javascript along with JQuery to load and display data dynamically in various containers that are activated depending on the user's interactions (it's an app for warehouse activities, such as managing picking lists an order preparations).

Typically, the startup code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menuDeliveryPreparations").click(function (e) {
       // Make some stuff visible when the user clicks this ...
    });

    $("#menuOrdersByArticles").click(function (e) {
       // Load some data ...
    });

    // Lots more event wiring...
});
```

Now, I see the benefits of moving all this to TypeScript so I can separate the various functionalities into modules and classes, have static typing, contained scrope and accurate Intellisense and all that.

The problem though is that once I start, I have no real idea how to refactor my existing code.
I can move related bits of functionality into separate modules and classes, but most of these are not really business objects, they are more UI-related code, and I still need to wire up all these event at some point.

So my questions are:

- Should I encapsulate everything in classes? But then, how do I instantiate each class and wire up the UI? Should I use a Winform-like paradigm where I wire up the the event within the class' constructor?
- JavaScript and its top-down execution model has a more natural functional feel that I struggle to translate into a class (object) oriented one (which TypeScript tends to promote). Am I completely out of it and is it a noob mistake to organise code like this anyway and that's why I'm struggling?

Comment: Worth saying - You can put functionality into modules and types, have contained scope and accurate intellisense even without TypeScript. You can even typehint for clever IDEs and the closure compiler and it'll verify them at compile time. It's perfectly possible to use classical inheritance in SPAs, your code just doesn't have any separation of concerns according to your example code. Good design of an SPA necessitates you separate UI logic like click handlers from business logic like loading app data and so on. Check out declarative data binding and separation of concerns

Comment: I would at last represent the data from "//load some data" with a class. You propably put these data.objects in an array of objects.

Then it is not a bad idea to put a namespace around everything, to remove the objects from the global variable.

To begin with it, copy all your JS into a .ts file and try to compile. It might take some time to find the right type-definitions for all your variables. You could start with "any" for everything, just to get the compile through. Then I would continue with the data-class,the array contaning the data and the methods that are part of the dataclass...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are struggling with how to handle binding your JavaScript to your DOM. This is something TypeScript will not fix for you. Does this mean you should not use TypeScript? No. The advantages you have provided are all valid, but of no concern to what is, at least IMHO, your real issue here: how do I wire up the UI?

But firstly I'll answer your two questions:

1. As much as possible. For example, let's assume you write a `Menu` class. That may contain all functionality required for the menu to work. Example code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=declare%20var%20JQuery;%0Adeclare%20var%20%24;%0A%0Aclass%20BackEndFacade%20%7B%0A%09constructor%28public%20baseUrl%3a%20string%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09getOrdersByArticle%28articleId%3a%20string%29%7B%0A%09%09return%20%24.get%28this.baseUrl%20+%20%22article/%22%20+%20articleId%20+%20%22/orders%22%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Menu%20%7B%0A%09constructor%28public%20element%3a%20JQuery,%20public%20facade%3aBackEndFacade%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09showOrderTypes%28%29%7B%0A%09%09this.element.find%28%22.clazz%22%29.show%28%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09showOrdersByArticle%28%29%7B%0A%09%09var%20data%20=%20this.facade.getOrdersByArticle%28this.element.find%28%22.clazz%22%29.val%28%29%29;%0A%09%09//%20do%20something%20with%20data%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20MenuFactory%20%7B%0A%09createMenu%28element%3aJQuery%29%7B%0A%09%09var%20menu%20=%20new%20Menu%28element,%20new%20BackEndFacade%28%22example.com%22%29%29;%0A%09%09//%20do%20the%20ui%20binding%20here%0A%09%09element.find%28%22#menuOrderTypes%22%29.click%28menu.showOrderTypes%28%29%29;%0A%09%09element.find%28%22#menuOrdersByArticles%22%29.click%28menu.showOrdersByArticle%28%29%29;%0A%09%7D%0A%7D). As you can see, this is another approach to structuring your application code, but it provides a better separation between responsabilities.
2. See 1 :)

But as I've said before, the concern you're expressing is about how to bind your elements to the JavaScript. In my example, I used the MenuFactory, but this is just one approach. You could choose to do all the binding in the constructor of Menu, but IMo this is dirty.

There is another way! Make use of a UI binding framework/library such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com). Using such a solution will tackle the problem of that boilerplate DOM binding code in your example.

I realize this is a far stretch from what you seem to be asking, but I feel this is what realy is bugging you.